# Huawei AGC push kit. Push-token's subscription to push topics disappears every day

Tags: android, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Mobile app has obtain a push token for device. Then mobile app send the token to backend. The backend subscribe the token on certain topics. Then i check the subscription via Postman request and get all topics that token was subscribed. The next day i check subscription via Postman request and get an empty array of topics and pushes by topics do not reach the device.
At the same time, it is important that we do not call the methods for unsubscribing and cleaning push topics for the token either on the backend or on the mobile app.
[image: check push topics request]

1. What were you doing when you ran into the problem?
   Answer:
   In order for a problem to arise, it is necessary to subscribe a push token to push topics and the next day (after 12-24 hours) check whether the token is subscribed to these topics and whether pushes by topics come to the device with this token
2. At which step did the problem occur?
   Answer:
   The problem occurs when a certain time passes or the next date arrives.
   At the same time, it is important that we do not call the methods for unsubscribing and cleaning push topics for the token either on the backend or on the client.
3. What were you expecting to happen?
   Answer:
   We expected push token's subscription to push topics to be permanent or long-term.
4. What actually happened?
   Answer:
   The next day, the push token turned out to be without a subscription to push topics.
5. What is the model and OS version of the device you were using?
   Answer:
   Huawei P40 Lite EMUI 12.0.0.285
6. Which version is the SDK of your kit? If the AR Engine is used, provide the AR Engine version number.
   Answer:
   @hmscore/react-native-hms-push": "6.7.0-300